# Datagrid itemssource is empty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When I select itemsource from datagrid, the value is null. Is it because I did not define imtemsource in datagrid?

This is how I add in a row into the datagrid:

```
this.dgProductList.Items.Add(new {ProductId=product.ProductId, Name=product.Name, Qty=1, Price=product.Price});
```

Here is my wpf:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgProductList" 
                                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                  FontSize="15"
                                  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#f0f0f0"
                                  VerticalGridLinesBrush="#f0f0f0"
                                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"      
                                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Image Height="10" Width="10" Source="{Binding Picture}" Stretch="Uniform"></Image>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductId}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Item" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Qty}" Header="Qty" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Price}" Header="Price" />
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Button Width="30" Name="btnDecrease" Content="-" />
                                                <Button Width="30" Name="btnIncrease" Content="+" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: When u run ur app, it shows data in grid. isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use binding to add items to datagrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridItemsSource}" ...
```

And in your view model (or something that is assigned to DataSource of your view):

```
public ObservableCollection<ProductData> DataGridItemsSource { get; set; }
```

ObservableCollection is the one to use in wpf binding because it implements pattern that allows datagrid to react to changes in this collection.

Answer (score 1):

you must use ItemsSource property of your grid

like

```
dgProductList.ItemsSource = YourData;
```

or

```
dgProductList.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { 

Source = YourData 
});
```

Comment: The datagrid row is added row by row

Comment: then you must add this "row by row" data in some list<products> and then assign it to itemsource.

Comment: Or simply bind data grid to `ObservableCollection` and forget about data grid. Then you can add delete and reorder this collection at will and all your changes will be visible on your view.